# Euro sign with "US International - PC" keyboard layout on Mac OSX

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

What it the shortcut to get an Euro sign with "US International - PC" keyboard layout?

[image]

Comment: What is your OS version?  Apple's keyboard is called ABC Extended for a long time already.  Is this something you downloaded from the web?

Comment: I've still never found anything called US Extended Umlaut anywhere and am curious where you got it

Comment: @TomGewecke i changed the question to ..."US International - PC"

Comment: Nice fix!  But what happened to your US Extended Umlaut?  I kind of collect unusual keyboards.  Do you still have it?  Aside from the Euro, US Extended and US International are very different animals...

Comment: Don't know how i got this strange keyboard layout on my system :D

Answer (score 3):

Press `ALT+Shift+2` and you get an €